# Android tablelayout and button resize

Tags: android, layout, button, tablelayout

here you are my problem: I want to do a layout that look like this grid in android:

[image]

In order to do so, I have created this layout:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0.3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clientimain"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
             />

    </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

So basically it is composed by 6 buttons in a table layout with the weight property setted correctly(or I hope so!). The result looks good until I'll try to set the background property of each button. In that case the button takes the height of the image that a put in (the width is ok). For instance if I set the background image which size is 96px x 96px the result look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this button "stretch" and to correctly center the image? 
I've tried to change the height property for each table row, to change the button max height property and also to change the button type with an imagebutton (and set the src property with the wanted icon) but i did not accomplished the wanted result.
I've also red the google documentation about supporting multiple screens and about each basic layout but I did not find any solution.
Thanks in advance to anyone that would like to help me!

Andrea

Comment: try and use android:scaleType="fitXY" on your button. also try and use http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html for this task

Comment: I tried the attribute android:scaleType="fitXY" but it did not work. I'll try to switch to grid layout if I can't find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the layout height of the table row as 0dip and set the weight as 1

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
```

This should fix your problem

---

Change

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/clientimain"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

to

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/clientimain"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

this could work, worth a try, in eclipse for me it renders right how you had it first, maybe you could try cleaning your project (Project > clean project) because it should be right as it is

---

You code should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clientimain"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

still not changing anything, how big is the size of the image?

Comment: I've already tried to do that but with no result.Now each row of the table has got that properties (height 0 and weight 1) but I still have that stretch. Thanks

Comment: First of all thanks for your support. I've tried to clean the project and also to replace my code with yours but when I select a background image, I still have the same problem. If I do not apply any image to the background of the button everything is ok and the grid looks like I wanted!

Comment: Hmm okay, ill try with images then, just wait a few, ill be back

Comment: I've tried with images of 256px x 256px in order to have a really high dpi

Comment: I have just remade your images, what you will want to do is make a 9 patch which will help give a better effect, ill give you a link soon

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try using this one:

https://rapidshare.com/files/2741870011/person.9.png

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I don't want to bother you! You have done enough! I'll try to do the nine patch by myself. Thank you very much SmartLemon!

Comment: I would appreciate it if you accepted my answer c: also I really dont mind, as long as its practice for me, just testing my own skills

Comment: What is your answer FabianCook? I have the same problem

Comment: Please refer to above answer

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but I recommend using GridView instead of TableRow layout.

I think GridView should work better because as it is implemented with view recycling and stuff inherited from AbsListView. GridView is more difficult to deploy because you have to use with Adapter but it will work efficiently if you have a lot of heavy views to load, such as images. [Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7088934)

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I applied the background image as

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

it worked fine.

I thought it was because of the size of the image so i applied other image with size 160X160 and the problem came back.
Than i applied the same 160X160 image to all the buttons and they aligned perfectly.
here is my code (The image Gender.png is of 160X160 pixels)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="0.3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clientimain"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/Gender" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:background="@drawable/Gender"/>

 </TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/Gender"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:background="@drawable/Gender"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" 
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/Gender" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
         android:background="@drawable/Gender"/>

</TableRow>


    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button77"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/Gender"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button75"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/Gender"
         />

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```