# Combine two LinearLayouts into one LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an two`LinearLayout` inside the `RelativeLayout`. I just want to do this  LinearLayout inside the one LinearLayout so that my child control will display inside 1 LinearLayout. so that I can make group of this LinearLayout and display 
with differnt background color  `android:background="@drawable/my_custom_background` so that all child control coupled into it.

see the below screen shot
[image]
code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0B95BA"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCont"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewCont"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Billing"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContBillingCall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutCont"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Call"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnContCall"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/PhoneCall" />
        <Button
            android:text="Email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Email" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and o/p should be above pic like **Contact** at center and two button (**Call and Email**) are below the contact same corner. also one thing I want to ask how I can create a space between these two buttons.

Comment: You are trying to combine 2 LinearLayouts with different orientations - it is not possible to combine them into one. Just use a RelativeLayout to position the controls without any LinearLayouts.

Comment: @adelphus i tried it but child control not shown on it.

Comment: @adelphus i tried android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCont" it shows me child control Contact , Call , Email in on one line i.e. in single line I want it on COntact above and Call and Email button below.

Comment: Which is why you use layout_below, layout_toLeftOf and other similar attributes to position elements inside RelativeLayouts. I think you need to read the documentation on how to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: You can use linearlayout instead of relative layout and then nest other linearlayouts inside it with desired orientation, width and height.

Comment: @AkashAmin I am bit confuse over Relative and Linear

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_linear_layout.htm

Comment: @MartinP Refer my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to only take one `Linear Layout` instead of two. Your `Text View` is child of your `Relative Layout`. I have applied some Modification to your `Layout`.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0B95BA">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewCont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Contact Billing"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewCont"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnContCall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="Call"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> **Note :** Apply your own Drawables and Background as you have in your OP.

Comment: thanks for reply I have 1 que what is android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher" ????

Comment: It is a `Drawable` image as you have used in your code `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/PhoneCall"` just same as this. Make it what ever you have just follow sequence of my answer.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if it is helpful to you thanks :).

Comment: I have also one question if I have one more linearlayout inside how I can do it. means same TextView and 2 buttons

Comment: If you use that kind the performance of the UI will not as you expected. You will not able to use `Relative Layout's` properties anymore. Best way to do is as this. If you need more two buttons then you can take new 1 `Linear Layout` and add that below other layouts.

Comment: what do you think about TableLayout

Answer (score 0):

Replace relative with linear you will get your desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0B95BA"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCont"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewCont"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contact Billing"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContBillingCall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutCont"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Call"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnContCall"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/PhoneCall" />
        <Button
            android:text="Email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonStyle"
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/Email" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want i LinearLayout for TextView and Buttons.

Comment: That's what in the code. LineayLayout for Textview and LineraLayout for buttons

Comment: I already implement it you jsut replace the relative layout with LinearLayout. I want TextView and Button in one Layout

Comment: I think that's not possible using Linear Layout. Because you want buttons side by side and for that you will required another layout. If you want to use one layout for both go for Grid Layout. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: You should never do this, regardless of the situation. Nested LinearLayouts have terrible performance.

Comment: what do you think about TableLayout

Comment: TableLayout is supported on all android versions , while GridLayout requires level 11 (Android ICS 4.0 ) or higher , but it can be easily added through support librarry v7 to support level 7( Android 2.1) or higher....From the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088821/grid-layout-vs-table-layout