# Which Layout GridLayout or TableLayout is suitable for this type of UI in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

[image]

I wrote this xml in Screenlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_height="50dp">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="Total (In USD)" android:textColor="#696969"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    <GridLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:columnCount="2" android:rowCount="3"
            android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="#696969">
                 <LinearLayout  android:layout_margin="1dp" android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="0"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="48dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Contract Amount" android:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="4523452345234" android:textColor="#696969"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                 <LinearLayout android:layout_row="0" android:layout_column="1"
                     android:layout_margin="1dp" android:background="#FFFFFF" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="48dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Actual Amount" android:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="45243" android:textColor="#696969"/>
                 </LinearLayout>
    </GridLayout>
```

[image]

But sadly this is the UI it is producing..
What is the best option to achieve this

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088821/grid-layout-vs-table-layout

Comment: What you have looks fine. Though, needs more styling. And the gray total at the top can also be within the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table layout is generally used for these types of layout.

Refer this for your question.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm.

Answer (score 2):

You should opt for table layout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) can help you write answers that will be accepted and upvoted.